# WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container

Tags: apache, jndi, tomcat8, catalina

Note, this did not help me [Tomcat Error: WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854848/tomcat-error-warning-failed-to-retrieve-jndi-naming-context-for-container)

When I run the Apache tomcat v8.0 server on my new workspace it produces a "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start." error.

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/appstore-api]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/appstore-api]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@716b94d]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@58623467]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
>   (bad signature)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 11 more
>
> Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy SEVERE: Failed to destroy
>   end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>
> Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>   INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33
>   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy SEVERE: Failed to
>   destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>
> Aug 19, 2016 8:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl
>   cleanUp WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/appstore-api]]
>   so no cleanup was performed for that container
>   javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class
>   loader    at
>   org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5540)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

I tried changing some parts of my code and when i remove the

```
<Context docBase="appstore-api" path="/appstore-api" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appstore-api">
      <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxIdle="10" maxTotal="20" maxWaitMillis="-1" name="jdbc/postgres" password="password" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appstore" username="postgres"/>
      </Context>
```

part of the code in server.xml of tomcat server. the error disappears but i am not able to call my enpoints since the "/appstore-api" path is not defined.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

the problem on my part is that this Maven dependency causes this error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```